# Best and easy way to add video to website

Tags: html, javascript, html5, jquery

I want to add videos to my website. I want to click on images and then to show video in "window" and start playing (popups like lightbox). I just don´t know what is best way to do it. I think one of the way is jQuery. I know that there is easy way with video tag in HTML5 but I want that this could be play on most browsers (not just with support HTML5, but not so old as IE6 :) ) and I don´t want to use flash or silverlight.

What options I have? Is jQuery the way? And how can I do this?
Thanks

Comment: Have you done any research on this? What have you found?

Comment: Yes I did but I didn´t found exactly what I found. F.e.: I found this: http://videolightbox.com/ but it is to complex and I want something easy as this: http://videobox-lb.sourceforge.net/ but it is with flash. I think I used it but if someone have better way or better script I would like to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done videolightbox like you mentioned, and then manually checked for devices like iPad to then swap in my HTML 5 Video tags instead of the flash object used by videolightbox. That is a pain. I found a new method recently which uses html 5 and Jquery. It's called VideoJS.

Goto http://videojs.com/ and read all about it.

Answer (score 2):

Focusing more on the "Best" part of your question and avoiding flash/silverlight I would go for html video with 3 codecs, or at least 2. Google webm, mp4 and Ogg Theora. Miro has a nice converter, it's not the best in terms of flexibility, but it's easy to use and free.

http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/

You also have a lot to gain if you invest some time learning the Popcorn player. What you can do with it is extraordinary.

http://popcornjs.org/

And if you want an easier tool you can use Maker. http://mozillapopcorn.org/maker